# access value of variable in different for/if statements

Tags: java, variables, scope

Im trying to use the playerSalaryDouble variable by using the value of the variable in the above if/else statement at the bottom in setPlayerSalary but it is showing as unresolved being out of scope, how can I get the value of the variable in this context.

```
                else{
                    double playerSalaryDouble = Double.parseDouble(playerSalary);
                }

                for(int z = 0; z < t.size(); z++){
                    for(int c = 0; c < t.get(z).getRoster().size(); c++){
                        if(playerName.equals(t.get(z).getRoster().get(c).getName())){
                            t.get(z).getRoster().get(c).setPlayerSalary(playerSalaryDouble);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The `playerSalaryDouble` variable needs to be declared in a scope that contains both the `if` / `else` and the `for` loop that needs to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-scope-error happens because you **defined** variable `playerSalaryDouble` in your `else` scope. So it can be used only **inside** this `else`. But your are trying to use it inside `for` cycle, which is outside of `else` scope.

If you want your variable `playerSalaryDouble` to be used outside of `else` you should **define** it outside. For example like this

```
// here we define
double playerSalaryDouble = 0;
if (...) {
    ...
} else {
    // here we initialize
    playerSalaryDouble = Double.parseDouble(playerSalary);
}

// now you can use playerSalaryDouble here
// but again, not in outer scope
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but then it states the variable has not been initialized. Only way I can get that error to go away is if I take it out of the else statement but I need it be initialized in the else statement.

Comment: @user18186941 Ok, initialize it with some dummy number, say `0`. If your `else` would be applied the variable would be re-assigned to `Double.parseDouble(playerSalary)`. See edits